# Is there a maximum size of return values in SOAP/PHP?

Tags: php, soap, return, max

I am calling a SOAP function in PHP, which returns a string array.
Is there a maximum allowed size of this returned array?
If yes, what is that maximum?

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231358/how-is-the-max-size-of-a-soap-message-determined

Comment: PHP itself does not limit the size of an array. It is only limited by the PHP memory_limit which can be set in the php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default amount of memory that PHP allows a script to allocate is 128 MB, and this includes variables such as arrays.

This 128 MB limit can be overridden globally by changing the `memory_limit` option in the `php.ini`.  Changing the setting to -1 means "unlimited".

It can also be overridden on a per script basis by using the `ini_set` function:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // Unlimited RAM
```

When "unlimited" is used, the size of your array is determined by the amount of available RAM on your machine.